# C++ Return array pointer doesn't work as intended

Tags: c++

I was writing code for a school assignment which is supposed to ask the user for a limit and call a function that would generate the values of a given series to an array and pass it back to the call method to get printed. Here's my code so far:

Header:

```
/*
 * series.h
 */

#ifndef SERIES_H_
#define SERIES_H_

// Direct calls for testing - DELETE AFTER
double log(int x);
double exp(int x);
double fib(int x);
double fac(int x);

// Global
enum SERIES {LOG, EXP, FIB, FAC};
void getSeries(SERIES _s, double _limit, int& _length, double *series);
double mean(double* _values, int length);
void printSeries(double* _series, int _length);

#endif /* SERIES_H_ */
```

CPP:

```
/*
 * series.cpp
 */
#include "series.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int x) {
    return (x == 1 ? x : x * factorial(x - 1));
}
double log(int x) {
    return ((double)x - ((double)(pow(x,2)) / (double)(2))
            + ((double)(pow(x,3)) / (double)(3)));
}
double exp(int x) {
    return (((double) 1) + ((double) x)
            + ((pow((double) x, 2)) / ((double) factorial(2)))
            + ((pow((double) x, 3)) / ((double) factorial(3)))
            + ((pow((double) x, 4)) / ((double) factorial(4))));
}
double fib(int x) {
    return (x < 2 ? x : (fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)));
}
double fac(int x) {
    return (x < 2 ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1));
}
void getSeries(SERIES _s, double _limit, int& _length, double *series) {
    _length = 0;

    switch (_s) {
    case LOG: {
        for (int i = 0; log(i) < _limit; i++) {
            series[i] = log(i);
            _length++;
        }
        break;
    }
    case EXP: {
        for (int i = 0; exp(i) < _limit; i++) {
            series[i] = exp(i);
            _length++;
        }
        break;
    }
    case FIB: {
        for (int i = 0; fib(i) < _limit; i++) {
            series[i] = fib(i);
            _length++;
        }
        break;
    }
    case FAC: {
        for (int i = 0; fac(i) < _limit; i++) {
            series[i] = fac(i);
            _length++;
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
double mean(double* _values, int length) {
    double sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += _values[i];
    }
    return (sum / length);
}
void printSeries(double* _series, int _length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "]" << _series[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 */

#include <iostream>
#include "series.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double _limit;
    int _length;
    double* series = new double;

    cout << "Series Calculator Application" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a limit:" << endl;
    cin >> _limit;
    cout << "Limit is " << _limit << endl;

    getSeries(LOG, _limit, _length, series);
    cout << "\nLOG Length is " << _length <<endl;

    cout << "------------TEST(LOG)" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < _length; i++){
        cout << "[" << i << "]" << log(i) << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------ACTUAL(LOG)" << endl;
    printSeries(series, _length);

    getSeries(EXP, _limit, _length, series);
        cout << "\nEXP Length is " << _length <<endl;

        cout << "------------TEST(EXP)" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < _length; i++){
            cout << "[" << i << "]" << exp(i) << endl;
        }
        cout << "------------ACTUAL(EXP)" << endl;
        printSeries(series, _length);
}
```

and when I run my main I get this from the console:

```
Series Calculator Application
Please enter a limit:
300
Limit is 300

LOG Length is 11
------------TEST(LOG)
[0]0
[1]0.833333
[2]2.66667
[3]7.5
[4]17.3333
[5]34.1667
[6]60
[7]96.8333
[8]146.667
[9]211.5
[10]293.333
------------ACTUAL(LOG)
[0]0
[1]0.833333
[2]2.66667
[3]7.5
[4]2.24151e-048
[5]1.96774e-259
[6]1.02756e-259
[7]96.8333
[8]146.667
[9]211.5
[10]293.333

EXP Length is 9
------------TEST(EXP)
[0]1
[1]2.70833
[2]7
[3]16.375
[4]34.3333
[5]65.375
[6]115
[7]189.708
[8]297
------------ACTUAL(EXP)
[0]1
[1]2.70833
[2]7
[3]16.375
[4]8.60084e-043
[5]1.56125e-259
[6]1.02899e-259
[7]189.708
[8]297
```

and there's my problem, as you can see, the actual implementation for elements 4, 5, and 6 does not match the test values. I have no idea how this happens. Please help!

Comment: Uugh! So many unnecessary parentheses. Learn your operator precedence tables and data type promotion rules!

Comment: `double* series = new double;` allocates a single `double` but `series` is the used as an array.

Comment: @Bath: The parens are fine. It's the over-abundance of [C-style] casts that's a problem.

Comment: @Francois: Why don't you post your comment as an answer? I agree that the failure to allocate memory for his double array is the root of the problem.

Comment: i am kind of curious what you think `double* series = new double;` does. You should wait until you have the length then use `double* series = new double[_length];`

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate `series`:

```
double* series = new double;
```

This allocates a single `double`. Using it as an array and accessing any element other than index `0` will lead to undefined behavior.

You could consider using `std::vector<double>` and add elements as needed.